# A string within a string in shell

Tags: shell, unix

Below line is the sample of my code

```
command mycommand /path/location arg1="my valu1" arg2="my value2"
```

when I am executing this command by hard-coding the argument value it works.

But when I am using below code format:

```
for i in "$@" do
str+="$i " 
done
command mycommand /path/location $str

where $str="arg1="my valu1" arg2="my value2""
```

It is not accepting  "my value1" as a single string. It is taking "my" as one  string and "value2" as a separate string.

Now if I use

```
command mycommand /path/location "$str"
```

then $str="arg1="my valu1" arg2="my value2"" as only one complete string. 
But I want command should execute in below format through program way.

```
command mycommand /path/location arg1="my valu1" arg2="my value2"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to append your arguments into a string just pass along `"$@"` to your actual command inside the script:

```
command mycommand /path/location "$@"
```

Comment: I have multiple arguments but I want to use some specific set of arguments. so $@ will contain all the arguments which is not applicable for me

Comment: Your own code `for i in "$@" do` is appending **every argument** to `str`

Comment: This is what I am doing. But getting the mentioned problem.

Comment: That's not the point, You showed a code that is trying to append every argument to `str` but now commenting `I want to use some specific set of arguments` so there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell which supports arrays (eg, bash), you would use an array:

```
command mycommand /path/location "${arr[@]}"
```

If your shell doesn't support arrays, you can use the positional paramters:

```
command mycommand /path/location "${@}"
```

A common hack is to use `set` reset the positional parameters.  That is, you can do:

```
set -- "arg one" "arg two"
```